# FIrebase auth log in as other user

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am building an E-learning platform.

We used WordPress but I built a react native app with a firebase database and now we want a react website that connects to the same database.

So now if a user has a problem, we can click a button in WordPress and log in as that user. It's handy if someone has a problem. Is this possible with firebase? I know it's the worse for security but I'm curious

I have tried to find some things about it but I can't see it.

Comment: "If a user has a problem" what do you mean by problem ? Please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

In Firebase, go to your project and go below "Authentication" page.
From here, click on "Sign in method". Below Sign in providers, press "Add new provider" - you can here see which login opportunities you have from Firebase authentication. Hope this answer your questions

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Update #2:

"So when for example a user "karin" has a problem i can login as "karin" and see what she sees." => Ok, I think I totally misunderstood your question.

If you want to login as a specific user you need to know his/her credentials, including the password. Or you need to build some specific screens in your app that (1) simulate the content shown to this user and (2) that you can access with your Admin profile.

---

#### Previous, irrelevant answer:

> I built a react native app with a Firebase database and now we want a
> react website which connects to the same database.... we can click a button in WordPress and log in as that user.

There is no problem at all to connect to the same Firebase database (the back-end) from different front-ends, including several web apps/sites or a mix of native mobile apps and a web app/site.

If I understand correctly, you want, from a Wordpress website to be able to authenticate against Firebase Auth and connect to the Firebase database. You could either use the JS SDK in your Wordpress pages (I've never tried and don't if it is feasible) OR use the [Firestore REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest) and the [Firebase Auth REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth) with, for example, the fecth API and the [Wordpress wrapper](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-api-fetch/) around this API.

---

**Update based on your comment below:** "I want that I can login as a user with Firebase Auth"

For that you will use the [`signInWithPassword` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-email-password) and get the user name contained in the Firebase Auth ID token returned by the Auth REST API after the login.

Comment: Yeah i know its no problem to connect two-front end to the same database. And i dont want to connect wordpress to firebase.

What i want is that i can login as a user with firebase auth. So when for example a user "karen" has a problem i can login as "karin" and see what she sees.

Comment: "And i dont want to connect wordpress to firebase. What i want is that i can login as a user with firebase auth."  Actually Firebase is the **entire** set of services including Firestore and Firebase Auth. (So, just to be precise, if you want a user to login to Firebase Auth from Wordpress you'll actually connect to Firebase). So for that you would use the Firebase Auth REST API to authenticate and get the user name contained in the token sent back by the Auth REST API after the login.

Comment: "So when for example a user "karen" has a problem i can login as "karin" and see what she sees." => Ok, think I totally misunderstood your question. If you want to login as a specific user you need to know his/her credentials. Or you need to build some specific screen in your app to simulate the content shown to this user.